# Apache camel getbody as custom class

Tags: java, apache-camel, javabeans

The question is rather simple, perhaps because I'm a little confused in the process.
What I'm trying to do is shown in the code example:

```
cc.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file://files?noop=true")
                    .split()
                    .tokenize("\n")
                    .split()
                    .method(SplitToken.class, "hashTokens")
```

and:

```
class SplitToken {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<HashMap<String, Integer>> hashTokens(final Exchange exchange) {
    List<String> oldstr = exchange.getIn().getBody(List<String>);
    //Create a key value hashmap from accumulated string list
    }
}
```

but returns error:

```
expression required.
```

Any ideas about how we can achieve getbody with desired class in general? (Since the first split method returns a string list but I can't retrieve it in second split, or can I?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember you cannot get generic list with `getBody`. This might work:

```
List<String> oldstr = (List<String>)exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
```

or even better you can make camel extract body for you with `@Body` annotation:

```
public static List<HashMap<String, Integer>> hashTokens(final Exchange exchange, @Body List<String> oldStr) {
    //Create a key value hashmap from accumulated string list
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: @Body seems like a nice solution, however I don't seem to understand how can I use the same method in camel aggregate(it takes 2 exchange)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your last question check out sub-section "Using POJOs as AggregationStrategy"/ "Different body types", from http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html

You could try sth like:

```
.pollEnrich("seda:foo", 1000, AggregationStrategies.beanAllowNull(MyUserAppender.class, "addUsers"))

public static final class MyUserAppender {

public List addUsers(List<String> names, User user) {
    if (names == null) {
        names = new ArrayList();
    }
    names.add(user.getName());
    return names;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a newly added feature. Definitely wanna try that.