# How to get generic types as exchange input body rather than casting?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

In **Apache camel** it's possible to get message body by it's own type by passing it's type into `exchange.getIn().getBody(Class<T> type)`. Lets say we want to get message body as `String` here is the example as following:

```
String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
```

In case of `Generic` or `Parameterized` types message, how do we get the object by it's own type rather than traditional object type casting. Here the pseudo code snippet for your realization:

```
package com.chorke.hmis.fusion.epoint;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("chorkeProcessor")
public class ChorkeProcessorImpl implements ChorkeProcessor{

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = null;
        list = exchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>.class);

        for (HashMap<String, Object> map : list) {
            for (String key : map.keySet()) {
               Object value= map.get(key);
               //TODO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Our expectation is as like as the example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache camel getbody as custom class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607811/apache-camel-getbody-as-custom-class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It simply can't be done, there's no `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>.class` class, the class is always a simple `ArrayList.class`,  that's just how Java generic types work. You'll either have to use the plain `ArrayList`:

```
@Component("chorkeProcessor")
public class ChorkeProcessorImpl implements ChorkeProcessor{

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list =  exchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class);

        for (HashMap<String, Object> map : list) {
            for (String key : map.keySet()) {
               Object value= map.get(key);
               //TODO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OR define and use your own type that just extends `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`:

```
// MyListOfMaps.java
public class MyListOfMaps extends ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> {
    // constructors, additional methods
}

// ChorkeProcessorImpl.java
@Component("chorkeProcessor")
public class ChorkeProcessorImpl implements ChorkeProcessor{

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        MyListOfMaps list =  exchange.getIn().getBody(MyListOfMaps.class);

        for (HashMap<String, Object> map : list) {
            for (String key : map.keySet()) {
               Object value= map.get(key);
               //TODO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should be careful with this approach if you do not create the list of maps yourself - you may need to provide a proper converter

Comment: For first case, have to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` over `public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception` method to avoiding compile time warning. Second one is looking good but wanna avoid declaring any wrapper class. It would be better to have any anonymous class.

Comment: "there's no ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>.class class" --> actually, you could create such a class using a TypeToken ( https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#typetoken ), but I don't know if Camel supports that out of the box.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, TypeToken is just an abstraction created to allow you to do things natively unsupported by Java but TypeToken is not a Class and cannot be used where class is expected